# How to dynamically add/remove item Fragments in MasterDetailFlow Android Java Example?

Tags: java, android, fragment, master-detail

I have an Android Java project I created with the "MasterDetailFlow" wizard.

I have obtained several items which I want to display as Master Item Fragments.

I used an Async task to do the network io so it didn't block UI updates on the master thread.

Now how do I update the ListFragment?  There's a list adapter, a dummy class holding the items...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple. You just call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: Because it's an async, it runs after the main onCreate code... So in this instance, I would pass the adapter to the async task, and then call notifyDataSetChanged()?

Comment: You can set adapter for you ListView in onCreate(). Then you can call notifyDataSetChanged() every time you want to update ListView.